# How to get a matrix with all combinations of three values in R?

Tags: r

Suppose we have a vector x with three values:

```
x <- c(0,1,2)
```

How to fill a matrix with 5 columns (V1, V2, V3, V4, V5) with combinations of all those values.

For example, we'd have:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
0   0  0  0  0 
0   0  0  0  1
0   0  0  1  1
...
0   1  0  0  0
...
1   1  1  1  1
...
1   2  1  0  1
...
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
 head(expand.grid(x,x,x,x,x))
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1    0    0    0    0    0
2    1    0    0    0    0
3    2    0    0    0    0
4    0    1    0    0    0
5    1    1    0    0    0
6    2    1    0    0    0
```

Comment: To make this extend to an arbitrary number of columns `col.count` you could do `expand.grid(list(x)[rep(1, col.count)])`.

Comment: It's a bit funny isn't it? We would make a good team, I suggest incomplete code and you improve it! :D